# Animate.css delay Animations, How to create slides with animate.css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a small issue .. am sure it has been solved, but have been able to see any stackoverflow solution on it.. so i thot to ask

I am creating a slide over a video, i want the slide to scroll in, the slide has no images, just captions

i am using the animate.css and jquery, the problem i have is i cant seem to time my slide to delay enough for viewers to read it, before it goes away for the next slide, another problem is i cant get the next slide in

Below are the codes

```
 <!--==========Video area==========-->
     <section>
<div class="content">
     <video autoplay="autoplay" muted="muted" loop="loop">
        <source src="view.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
<div class="content-slide">
    <h1>HESI-GEOMATICS</h1>
    <p>the Earth Brings life</p>
</div>               
<div class="content-slide">
    <h1>HELLO</h1>
    <p>Welcome to our site</p>
</div>       
  <div class="content-slide">
    <h1>GEOMATICS</h1>
    <p>Join Us</p>
</div>         
    </section>
    <!--==========End Video area==========-->
```

Now my CSS code

```
.content {
position: relative;
width: 100%;
}
.content:before {
/*Note: z-index of 1 or 0 can be used here*/
content: '';
position: absolute;
background: rgba(31, 26, 23, 0.7);
/*background: rgba(93, 171, 217, 0.3);*/
/*
Note: Valid code (color HesiBlue: #5DABD9)
background-color: #1F1A17;
opacity: 0.4;
filter: alpha(opacity=40);*/
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
}

 .content-slide {
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) ;
-ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
/*min-height: 100%;*/
z-index: 1;
   /* background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);*/
}
  .content-slide h1 {

text-align: center;
font-size: 65px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-weight: 300;
color: #fff;
   /* padding-top: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;*/
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
     /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    }
    .content-slide p {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    color: #aaa;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 1.5s;
    /*-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;*/
    }
```

My JQuery is

```
 $(function(){
        /*Declarations*/

    var animationEnd = 'webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend';
    var contentH1 = ".content-slide h1";
    var contentP = ".content-slide p";

    /* reason we use one() instead on on() will only listen to the event once and then it will unbind itself */
    $(window).on( "load", function(){

        $(contentH1).addClass('animated bounceInLeft');

        $(contentP).addClass('animated bounceInRight').one(animationEnd,
            function() {
            $(this).removeClass('animated bounceInRight');

           // event.stopPropagation();
        });
    });
});
```

How can i delay my animation i tried .delay(15000) in jquery but its no use

Comment: please.. i need help with this...

Answer (score 0):

try apply the CSS rule "`animation-delay: 3s;`" to the element that has the animate.css class applied to it.

For example if the html element `<img src="..." class="animated flash">` has animate.css applied to it
then apply

```
img{
animation-delay: 3s;
}
```

to delay the animation by 3 seconds.